# React - possible to use the back button in browser in a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to build a dynamic form where the data sent from the server will be rendered by the client. The form will have X amount of steps, decided by the data.

I have my component Form rendering X amount of components Steps.

My problem now is that since it's all the same component, Form, there's not possible for the user to click on the back button to go to the previous step in the Form. I somehow need to keep my URL in sync with my Form/Steps.

What would be the best solution to this problem? Using HashRouter and using Route with "/:id/:step"(how would this work)? Pushing the routes in automatically using useHistory-hook?

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest case as I think is to create parent component with state `step` and change it when a user go or return to step. Based on `step` you should render the appropriate step.

Answer (score 0):

A css solution would be to break the form into sections and show 1 section at a time, when some one clicks on the navigation buttons of the form a state update triggers another section to be shown while hidihng the current one. This can be done using CSS transitions, you can look into react-transition-groups to make css transitions with react easier

Comment: Thank you, will definitely look into that!